# Why PyQt is showing "not responding" in title bar of window on my Anaconda (Spyder)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, anaconda

After running the program in the background, when I execute I get (Not responding in the title bar).

[image]

And if I try to close it shows this

[image]

And after closing it start giving kernel killing message as shown in the screen on the right side.

[image]

I am running "Anaconda-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64". Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Do you not need `app.exec_()` as the final line of code when using (Spyder?)

Comment: @three_pineapples Thank you so much. But why do we have to include it?

Comment: @three_pineapples hi, it is working fine now for first time. But if I execute it  again the window doesn't show up and it starts giving  same error of kernel dying error.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder does some weird things where it doesn't run code in a new process and so it can keep things around from the last time the code was run. Quite frankly I would find this extremely annoying, and so I don't use Spyder (which means this answer is potentially not perfect, and someone else should probably post another with a better solution!)

What you need to do is check to see if the `QApplication` already exists, and only create it if does not.

```
if QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication.instance()
else:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

...

app.exec_()
```

I think you should always be calling `app.exec_()`, regardless of whether the `QApplication` has been created before.

Personally though, I launch python files from a standard windows command line so that I always know it is starting fresh.

Answer (score 1):

[Not Responding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HiF8.jpg)

You just need to add this: *app.exec_()* at the end of the code

[Working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzViw.jpg)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app =  QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget() 
window.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
window.setWindowTitle("PyQt Ecuador")

window.show()
app.exec_()
```